# Google Analytics Event and Social Reporting on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, google-analytics

I'm using the latest version of Google analytics for iOS (up to this post date).
The pageViews are logged and reported correctly but the **events** and **social** events aren't. Here are some snippets of my code:

```
@interface RootViewController : GAITrackedViewController
```

All my ViewControllers inherit the **GAITrackedViewController**

```
[self.tracker sendEventWithCategory:@"Twitter" withAction:@"Tweet" withLabel:@"Tweet App Info" withValue:nil];
[self.tracker sendSocial:@"Twitter" withAction:@"Tweet App Info" withTarget:nil];
```

I call this from my view controller to log an event of sending a tweet, but when I check my Google analytics (Engagement->Events->OverView) no events are logged. This is not real time data, I'm talking about 3 days of testing without events reported.

I'm following this guide by [Google Mobile App Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/events), but when using

```
[tracker sendEvent]
```

I get errors so I use

```
[self.tracker sendEvent]
```

and I think it uses the default tracker of the app.

Any help with this problem ?

Comment: Any luck with this? I am seeing similar results.

Comment: @ChrisWagner Unfortunately It wasn't solved and I ended up using Flurry. Anyway, flurry is well documented and very popular in the iOS devs community but I wanted to give Google Analytics its try.

Answer (score 0):

for me, the [self.tracker ...] or [tracker ...] calls did not work. I ended up using the shared instance default tracker as follows:

```
[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker sendEventWithCategory:@"TAC_Agree" withAction:@"buttonClick" withLabel:@"" withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
```

This definitely works for me.

Comment: instead of `[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]` you could just use `@(0)`